# Rstudioで日本語の表示が文字化けしてしまう

Tags: r, rstudio

最近国内製のノートパソコンを買って、Rで日本語データの処理しようとしたら日本語の表示に中々苦戦しています。例えばただのPrint関数で日本語の文字が正しく表示されません。コードの一例とセッションインフォなどを添付しております。

Localeの変更などはもう結構やってみたんですけど全部だめです。

日本人でない者ですので、詳しく説明していただくと助かります。よろしくお願いいたします。

```r
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "japanese")

print("日本語")

Sys.getlocale()
sessioninfo::session_info()
```

```
> Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "japanese")
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Japanese_Japan.932;LC_CTYPE=Japanese_Japan.932;LC_MONETARY=Japanese_Japan.932;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Japanese_Japan.932"
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Japanese_Japan.932;LC_CTYPE=Japanese_Japan.932;LC_MONETARY=Japanese_Japan.932;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Japanese_Japan.932"
> 
> print("日本語")
[1] "\u65e5\u672c\u8a9e"
> 
> sessioninfo::session_info()
- Session info --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
 os       Windows 10 x64              
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language ja_JP.UTF-8                 
 collate  Japanese_Japan.932          
 ctype    Japanese_Japan.932          
 tz       Asia/Tokyo                  
 date     2021-03-19                  

- Packages ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package     * version date       lib source        
 assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 cli           2.2.0   2020-11-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 dplyr         1.0.2   2020-08-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 ellipsis      0.3.1   2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 fansi         0.4.1   2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 generics      0.1.0   2020-10-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 glue          1.4.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 hms           0.5.3   2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 insight       0.11.0  2020-11-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 jsonlite      1.7.2   2020-12-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)
 lifecycle     0.2.0   2020-03-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 magrittr      2.0.1   2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 pillar        1.4.7   2020-11-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 purrr         0.3.4   2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 qualtRics     3.1.4   2021-01-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 R6            2.5.0   2020-10-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 readr         1.4.0   2020-10-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 rlang         0.4.9   2020-11-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 rstudioapi    0.13    2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 sjlabelled    1.1.7   2020-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 stringi       1.5.3   2020-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 tibble        3.0.4   2020-10-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 tidyr         1.1.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 tidyselect    1.1.0   2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 utf8          1.1.4   2018-05-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)
 vctrs         0.3.5   2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
 withr         2.3.0   2020-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)

[1] C:/Users/gagno/Documents/R/win-library/4.0
[2] C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.4/library
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rを4.0.2にダウングレードしたら解決しました。もし同じような状況があればダウングレードしてみてください。

R4.0.4Patchedでも解決可能だそうです。